# split strings multiple words or dashes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a string into multiple strings.  I'm using the re library but i ran into a problem.  Say my string is" "Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826"  I it will work if I do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826"
>>> re.split('\W+', x)
```

it would return

```
['Yakima', 'WA', '4660', '12051', '49826']
```

Which I would want it to.  But the problem I'm having is if the city has a (-) or a space in the city, how would be able to keep the city together in its own string.  I"ll be dealing with multiple cities, and some have 2 to 3 work cities and some have dashes.  I need to keep 3 data structures with the city and state combined, the coordinates, and the population.

```
>>> x = "Winston-Salem, NC[3610,8025]131885"
>>> re.split('\W+', x)
['Winston', 'Salem', 'NC', '3610', '8025', '131885']
```

or

```
>>> x = "West Palm Beach, FL[2672,8005]63305"
>>> re.split('\W+', x)
['West', 'Palm', 'Beach', 'FL', '2672', '8005', '63305']
```

and I want:

```
['Winston-Salem', 'NC', '3610', '8025', '131885']
['West Palm Beach', 'FL', '2672', '8005', '63305']
```

Answer (score 6):

You can split by `[^\w\s-]+`:

```
>>> x = "Winston-Salem, NC[3610,8025]131885"
>>> re.split('[^\w\s-]+', x)
['Winston-Salem', ' NC', '3610', '8025', '131885']

>>> x = "West Palm Beach, FL[2672,8005]63305"
>>> re.split('[^\w\s-]+', x)
['West Palm Beach', ' FL', '2672', '8005', '63305']
```

`[^\w\s-]+` basically means not alphanumeric (`a-zA-Z0-9_`), not whitespace character and not `-`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try splitting by `,` or `[` or `]`:

```
re.split('[,\[\]]', x)
```

**Demo:**

```
import re

L = ["Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826",
"Winston-Salem, NC[3610,8025]131885",
"West Palm Beach, FL[2672,8005]63305"]

for e in L:
    print re.split('[,\[\]]', e)

>>> ['Yakima', ' WA', '4660', '12051', '49826']
>>> ['Winston-Salem', ' NC', '3610', '8025', '131885']
>>> ['West Palm Beach', ' FL', '2672', '8005', '63305']
```